# Navigation in OnAppearing() method works wrong

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, maui

I got 2 pages FirstPage which is Content and SecondPage which is Tabbed page
FirstPage contains OnAppearing method

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (Preferences.Get("IsLogged", false) == true && App.BugFix == true)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainTabPage());
            });
        }
    }
```

When the conditions is true it navigated to the TabPage ( for example it has 3 children pages), but i can see first children(page) and there is no ToolBar [image how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwhV0.png)

I changed this part of code

```
Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainTabPage());
            });
```

to

```
Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainTabPage());
            });
```

and now it works as expected, but it has visual problem, before it navigates to the tab page it shows the FirstPage for like a second.

Comment: Why is your TabbedPage a [ModalPage?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal)

Comment: I don't really get you. Is it because i push it modalAsync?

Comment: Do you know what a modal page does is the question...

Comment: From what i know, Any page can be modal. A page becomes modal when we push it on modal stack and it becomes active also user cannot navigate back from modal page till a task is completed or cancelled and we don't have nav bar. Oh i probably got you. Now the Task.Run works fine. Ty

Comment: I recommend adding Your Answer below, showing how you solved it. This may help others in the future.